# Dialyzer Errors call to missing or unexported function gen_server:call/4

Tags: erlang, gen-server, dialyzer

```
stop_link(UserDefined) ->
  gen_server:call({local, UserDefined}, terminate, [], []),
  ok
```

I am using dialyzer to fix warning in erlang code, I came across this mistake which reads missing or unexported function `gen_server:call/4`.

I am not able to understand what is wrong with this can, anyone please guide me in what the mistake is *I had just started with Erlang I would greatly appreciate if you can explain it briefly*.

Comment: I don't see any four argument version of `gen_server:call` in the documentation: http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#call-3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things wrong with this code. Here goes...

The reason the `start_link` function is called that is because it starts the process and [**links** to it](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#links). Your `stop` function should just be called `stop`.

The [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#call-3) for `gen_server:call/2,3` shows up two problems with this code:

1. You don't need the `{local, Name}` form with `gen_server:call`. You only need it when calling `gen_server:start_link` (and only then if you want a registered name for your process). For calling local names, just use `Name`. Or the process ID.
2. There isn't a variant of the function with arity 4 (i.e. 4 parameters). The 3-arity variant takes a timeout. You probably want the 2-arity one.

I *suspect* that you're trying to specify an arbitrary function in `gen_server:call` (i.e. you want to call the `terminate` function). That's not how this works.

`gen_server:call(NameOrPid, Request)` results in a call to `handle_call(Request, From, State)`. See [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_call-3).

In *that* function, you can match the request and do the appropriate thing. Something like this:

```
handle_call(frob, _From, State) ->
    % do whatever 'frob' means.
    {reply, ok, NewState};
```

(that `;` might be a `.`, depending on whether this is the final `handle_call` clause).

If you really want the server to stop, you should just do the following:

```
handle_call(terminate, _From, State) ->
    {stop, meh, State}.
```

*That* will result in a call to `terminate`.

Oh, and if you're only just learning Erlang, you probably don't want to be running dialyzer until you've got a bit more experience. It's a bit ... tricky ... for the uninitiated. Though it did find this mistake, which was nice.

Comment: What does [], [] these things do at the end of the second line, i removed one of those square brackets to match the gen_server:call/3 the error has been fixed.      gen_server:call({local, UserDefined}, terminate, []),

Comment: Those are just empty lists. Removing one of them will fix the arity of the function call, but it still won't work, because an empty list is not a valid timeout value.